# ttk:Combobox foreground color change doesn't work properly. What's wrong?

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, tk-toolkit

Attemps to reliably change the text color in a ttk::Combobox fail.
It happens for me on Windows 10 with the native theme.

The following code creates two comboboxes with their foreground color set to red.
Selecting an option in one of them then the other, back and forth, shows that the foreground color alternates between black and red.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
ttk.Style().configure('Red.TCombobox', foreground='red')
combo = ttk.Combobox(root, values=('one', 'two', 'three'), state='readonly')
combo.configure(style='Red.TCombobox')
combo.grid(row=0, column=0)
combo2 = ttk.Combobox(root, values=('one', 'two', 'three'), state='readonly')
combo2.configure(style='Red.TCombobox')
combo2.grid(row=0, column=1)
root.mainloop()
```

Here's what it looks like:

[image: combo foreground color illustration]

How can I make it red at least when the text is not marked as selected?
(a solution for the selected text would be appreciated as well)

Comment: Reproducible on a windows 11. At first seemed like the issue is due to global theme `'Red.TCombobox'` but this happens even with just one `Combobox` and another widget to switch focus. Looks like a weird bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modifying your Style instance from:

```
ttk.Style().configure('Red.TCombobox', foreground='red')
```

to:

```
ttk.Style().map(
    'Red.TCombobox',
    foreground=[('readonly', 'red')],
    selectforeground=[('readonly', 'red')],
)
```

Using `map()` here allows you to specify a "statespec" (i.e., the widget state to which your style applies) - you can read more [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tkinter.ttk.Style.map)

**BONUS - COLORING THE LIST ITEMS:**

If you want *all* of your list items to be red, you (unfortunately) can't use the Style() class. Instead, you can use `Tk.option_add` - you can read more [here](https://ttkbootstrap.readthedocs.io/en/version-0.5/widgets/combobox.html#create-a-custom-style) (scroll up a bit to the 'Note' just above "Create a custom style")

In this case, you'll want to add

```
root.option_add('*TCombobox*Listbox.foreground', 'red')
```

anywhere before `root.mainloop()` (preferably just after `root = tk.Tk()`)

Comment: Do you think it's a bug that needs to be reported or an expected behavior?

Comment: @SoleSoul Which, the list item coloring bit? I'm honestly not sure, but I'd lean towards "expected behavior".

Comment: No, I meant the fact that foreground=red doesn't apply to readonly foreground as well by default. Isn't the simple case to have the same color all the time? The current behaiour seems unintentional as the color changes in unexpected times.

Comment: @SoleSoul You know, that's a good point and I'm afraid I'm not sure!